# creating menus for anchors in djangocms

Tags: python, django-cms

I installed and played a bit with DjangoCMS and while I was able to create pages, I'm not sure how to create menus.

Is there an entity for menu item or do I need to define a page for every menu item? What if I want the menu item to link to an anchore in the page? is it possible? (I can't seem to configure anywhere in a page a hash sign (#) - I get a validation error)

Comment: In case anyone will find it useful, I have found how to create anchor menu items - through the redirect_url in the page advanced settings (write "#foo" in the redirect url and clicking on this menu item will get you to foo anchor)

Comment: Thanks for the info! I had issues with your explanations, maybe you should redact a more complete answer. I had to use `/#anchorname` in the redirection field because without the `/` it was complaining that the link wasn't valid. Also, I created sub-pages and had to uncheck the main page menu, and check the sub-pages menu for it to display properly, it would be worth to put that in an answer. However this solution doesn't work perfectly for me because that's redirections and not just internal links, so my scrollspy doesn't behave correctly with it.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure of the best way for header and footers. You can try including the in the base.html. If you define your footer in a separate html file, u can insert it into the pages your want with:

```
{% include "path/to/file.html" %}
```